# TypeError: Object of type ObjectId is not JSON serializable

Tags: python, flask

Estoy realizando una Api Rest con Python. A la hora de intentar hacer el metodo POST, se me crea el json y me lo guarda en la base de datos, pero me aparece este error.

```
TypeError: Object of type ObjectId is not JSON serializable
```

```
from flask import Response

from src.hotel.models import Hotel

class HotelApi(Resource):
    def get(self):
        hotels = Hotel.objects.to_json()
        return Response( hotels, mimetype = 'application/json', status = 200);

    def post(self):
        
        parser = reqparse.RequestParser()
        parser.add_argument("name", required = True, help = "No has introducido ningun nombre")
        parser.add_argument("place", required = True, help = "No has introducido ningun lugar")
        args = parser.parse_args()

        hotel = Hotel(name = args["name"], place = args["place"])

        hotel.save()

        return hotel
```

Esta es la funcionalidad que tengo hasta el momento en el controlador, la funcion de obtener todos los datos con GET funciona perfectamente.

Os dejo tambien el Json que me crea( estoy haciendo las comprobaciones con POSTMAN)

```
{
        "_id": {
            "$oid": "606b0a3441e552a826f76bc4"
        },
        "name": "name",
        "place": "place"
}
```

Aqui os dejo la configuracion con Mongo y app

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_mongoengine import MongoEngine

app = Flask(__name__)

app.config['MONGODB_SETTINGS'] = {
    'db': 'api-rest-mongo',
    'host': 'localhost',
    'port': 27017
}

db = MongoEngine(app)

from flask_restful import Api
from src.restful.controllers import HotelApi, HotelApiId

api = Api(app)
api.add_resource(HotelApi, '/api/hotel')
api.add_resource(HotelApiId, '/api/hotel/<string:id>')
```

Aquí dejo el modelo, tiene parte de otra parte del curso que estoy haciendo, por lo que hay codigo que tiene que ver con otro controlador

```
import mongoengine as models
from flask_mongoengine import BaseQuerySet
from flask_mongoengine.wtf import model_form

class Hotel(models.Document):
    peticion GET, ETC
    _id = models.ObjectIdField()
    name = models.StringField(required = True, max_lenght = 150)
    place = models.StringField(required = True)

    meta = { 'queryset_class' : BaseQuerySet }

    def setByForm(self, form):
        self.name = form.name.data
        self.place = form.place.data
```

Muchas gracias por la ayuda, cualquier otro dato que necesiteis no dudies en preguntar.

Comment: Hola! En tu post no estás devolviendo ningún JSON ¿es normal? Por otra parte, ese error es de parsing, por favor, muéstranos el código completo ¿a quién le entregas "hotel"  en tu post?

Comment: Hola, gracias por la respuesta. añadí el modelo y la conexion a Mongo y configuracion de app. El hotel lo unico que hago es guardarlo en la bbdd, el return lo hago, ya que como explica el curso que estoy haciendo y comprobé tambien quitandolo, sino me devuelve NULL